# How do I setup my g++ compiler for C++11?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I tried a basic program:

```
// ThreadExample.cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void task1(string msg)
{
    cout << "task1 says: " << msg;
}

int main()
{
    thread t1(task1, "Hello");
    t1.join();
}
```

One I actually found on stackoverflow, but I tried compiling it using:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -pthread ThreadExample.cpp -o ThreadExample -lm
```

However, I keep getting an error that thread is undeclared. I have version 4.7.1 of the MinGW GNU for Windows. Is there something I can change so I can use C++11?

Comment: Does MinGW support posix threads?

Comment: also try to put -pthread in the end of g++ command, order matters

Comment: Yeah. Change `c++0x` to `c++11` to use C++11. However, I doubt that this has anything to do with the thread library...

Comment: It looks like it doesn't support posix threads, because Windows isn't a POSIX system:

    http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library

Does anyone know if this means I have to use a *nix OS, like Ubuntu to use c++11 && its thread class? I am new to c++11.

Comment: You could use Visual Studio.  Its C++11 library implementation is mostly complete.

Comment: It's certainly possible to get a MinGW build that uses Pthreads, I think @rubenvb can probably give more info. Paging rubenvb ... damn, naming a user doesn't do anything if they haven't contributed to the question

Comment: The [builds here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/) have support, however, there is a lot of overhead, and I recommend using visual studio instead on windows.

Comment: @JesseGood: A lot of overhead to get it working?  Or a lot of overhead in the produced code?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: In the produced code, at least in my tests compared to visual studio.

Comment: @leemes, `-std=c++0x` and `-std=c++11` do exactly the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Noone has contributed an implementation of `<thread>`, `<mutex>` etc for Mingw yet, except when using Mingw with (optional) Pthreads support via a third-party pthreads implementation.

I started a thread at http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/libstdc++/2012-05/msg00020.html with some suggestions for implementing the missing features in terms of Windows native threads, but as I don't have a Windows machine and noone else has volunteered to do anything, nothing happened.  I have almost zero interest in implementing it myself, because I never develop for Windows so it would be of no use to me whatsoever, and I would rather spend my limited free time implementing things I will actually use.  If anyone wants to work on it I'd happily advise them and review their code and help shepherd it into GCC.